# Docker LocalStack Extension error: localstack.utils.bootstrap : Error while creating container: Docker process returned with errorcode 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

I am attempting to run LocalStack in Docker on Windows 11 via the [LocalStack Docker Extension](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/tools/localstack-docker-extension/).

After following the instructions for installing and configuring it, and after it successfully pulls a `localstack/localstack` image, when I click Start, I receive the following error (`localstack.utils.bootstrap : Error while creating container: Docker process returned with errorcode 1 ?`):

[image]

There is very little information online related to this specific error, and nothing at all that's an exact match for my detailed error message.

I've tried deleting all my containers/images and re-initializing the LocalStack Extension, but to no avail.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?  (PS: I should mention that I'm using my work PC on which I don't have admin permissions.)

Comment: Usually when this happens you can go to the "Containers" section in docker desktop and there should be a container exited or created where you should be able to get some more info on why it exited with error code 1